# What is the name of this method?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, discrete-logarithms

I have been doing some research into discrete log problem in the form of

$$f(x) = g^{\operatorname{floor}(x)} \; \text{mod } p.$$

Interestingly I found that there is a function $t(x)$ where $t(f(x))= x$. More importantly, the method by which we find $t(x)$ is as follows

$$t(x) = f(f(x)).$$

This will work for example where $g = 2$, $p= 5$.

But for $g = 5$ and $p = 7$ we get

$$t(x) = f(f(f(x))).$$

So does anyone know what this method is called?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematics. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration ?